# Calling a function that takes a pointer to the base class using pointer to a derived class that inherits the base class privately

Tags: c++, inheritance

If you attempt something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Base {
};

class Derived: private Base {
};

void sayHello(Base* base) {
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    Derived *derived_ptr = new Derived();
    sayHello(derived_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

You get this compilation error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:24:13: error: ‘Base’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Derived’
   24 |     sayHello(derived_ptr);
      | 

~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Which is expected.

But if I call the sayHello function from within in the derived class, somehow this seems to be working.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base;

void sayHello(Base* base) {
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}

class Base {
};

class Derived: private Base {
    public:
        void derivedClassSayHello() {
            sayHello(this);
        }
};

int main()
{
    Derived *derived_ptr = new Derived();
    derived_ptr->derivedClassSayHello();

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain why the second example works?

I don't know what is happening here, but by following the second example, I am able to use private members of the Derived class in the sayHello function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    public:
        int x;
        Base(int xx) : x(xx) {
        }
};

void sayHello(Base* base) {
    cout << "Hello " << base->x << endl;
}

class Derived: private Base {
    public:
        Derived() : Base(10) {}
        void derivedClassSayHello() {
            sayHello(this);
        }
};

int main()
{
    Derived *derived_ptr = new Derived();
    derived_ptr->derivedClassSayHello();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
Hello 10

Answer (score 2):

This is simply because `derivedClassSayHello()` is a member of its class, and therefore has access to its private members or base classes.

That is precisely what private inheritance means: only members of the class have access to other private members.

It is the ***caller*** that attempts to perform the conversion from the derived class to the base class. And since the caller is a member of a class it has full access to its private members.